# How to find the general term formula of arithmetic progression satisfying this condition?

Tags: differential-equations

The known conditions for the question are as follows:

The tolerance of Arithmetic progression {a [n]} is d, and d>1. Let b [n]==(n ^ 2+n)/a [n]. Note that S [n] and T [n] are the sum of the first n terms of the sequence {a [n]} and {b [n]}, respectively. If 3a [2]=3a [1]+a [3], S [3]+T [3]=21, find the general term formula a [n]

```
ClearAll["`*"]
RSolve[{b[n] == (n^2 + n)/a[n], a[n] - a[n - 1] > 1, 
  a[n] - a[n - 1] == a[n - 1] - a[n - 2], 3 a[2] == 3 a[1] + a[3], 
  a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + b[1] + b[2] + b[3] == 21, a[1] b[1] == 2}, 
 a[n], n]

RSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of -a[-1+n]+a[n]>1 in the first argument {b[n]==(n+n^2)/a[n],-a[-1+n]+a[n]>1,-a[-1+n]+a[n]==-a[-2+n]+a[-1+n],3 a[2]==3 a[1]+a[3],a[1]+a[2]+a[3]+b[1]+b[2]+b[3]==21,a[1] b[1]==2}.
```

Unable to find using the above methods

```
In[5]:= ClearAll["`*"]
RSolve[{b[n] a[n] == n^2 + n, a[n + 1] - a[n] == d, 
  a[n] == a[1] + (n - 1) d, a[n + 1] - a[n] == a[n + 2] - a[n + 1], 
  3 a[2] == 3 a[1] + a[3], 
  a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + b[1] + b[2] + b[3] == 21, 
  a[1] b[1] == 2}, {a[n], b[n]}, n]

Out[6]= RSolve[{a[n] b[n] == n + n^2, -a[n] + a[1 + n] == d, 
  a[n] == d (-1 + n) + a[1], -a[n] + a[1 + n] == -a[1 + n] + a[2 + n],
   3 a[2] == 3 a[1] + a[3], 
  a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + b[1] + b[2] + b[3] == 21, 
  a[1] b[1] == 2}, {a[n], b[n]}, n]
```

Not resolved yet

````
In[7]:= ClearAll["`*"]
Solve[{a[1] == d, 
  3 a[1] + 3 d + 2/a[1] + 6/(a[1] + d) + 12/(a[1] + 2 d) == 21, 
  d > 1}, {a[1], d}]

Out[8]= {{a[1] -> 3, d -> 3}}
```
````

Comment: What does it mean to be the tolerance d of the sequence a[n]? Note that you haven't used d in your RSolve.

Comment: d==a[n]-a[n-1]  this

Comment: a[n] - a[n - 1] > 1

Comment: `a[n]==3*n, b[n]==(n+1)/3` Think carefully. Test it even more carefully.

Comment: ```ClearAll["`*"]
RSolve[{b[n] == (n^2 + n)/a[n], a[n + 1] - a[n] == d, 
  a[n] == a[1] + (n - 1) d, a[n + 1] - a[n] == a[n + 2] - a[n + 1], 
  3 a[2] == 3 a[1] + a[3], 
  a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + b[1] + b[2] + b[3] == 21, 
  a[1] b[1] == 2}, {a[n], b[n]}, n]```don't get the answer yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bill has answered: d=3, and a[n]=3 n and b[n]= (n+1)/3.

`RSolve` can be applied once a[1] and d are found. a[1]b[1]=2 just follows from definitions and does not aid solution.

In an ugly way here is an approach:

```
{u, v} = {a[2] - a[1], a[3] - a[2]} /. 
   Quiet@Solve[{a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + 2/a[1] + 6/a[2] + 12/a[3] == 21, 
       3 a[2] == 3 a[1] + a[3]}, {a[1], a[2], a[3]}][[1]];
Quiet@Solve[u == v, {a[1], a[2], a[3]}]
```

`{u,v}` is sequence of differences, then `Solve` is used to find sequence with equal differences. Note this yields {a[1] -> 3}}.

Using this and back substitution:

```
Chop[N[Quiet@
    Solve[{a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + 2/a[1] + 6/a[2] + 12/a[3] == 21, 
       3 a[2] == 3 a[1] + a[3]}, {a[1], a[2], a[3]}][[1]] /. 
   a[1] -> 3]]
```

yields: {a[2.] -> 6., a[3.] -> 9.}

Testing:

```
 {a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + 2/a[1] + 6/a[2] + 12/a[3] == 21, 
  3 a[2] == 3 a[1] + a[3]} /. {a[1] -> 3, a[2] -> 6, a[3] -> 9}
```

yields `{True, True}`

Now using `RSolve`:

```
RSolve[{a[n] == a[n - 1] + 3, a[1] == 3}, a[n], n]
```

yields `{{a[n] -> 3 n}}` as per @Bill. b[n] follows from its definition.

Note: 3a[2]==3a[1]+a[3] $\iff$ 3d=3 (a[2]-a[1])=a[3] is good starting point for a guess...